# Can I proof this statement "Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ If $x^3-x>0$ then $x>-1$" like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

Proof by contrapositive

We want to prove "If $x \leqslant-1$  then  $x^3-x\leqslant0$"

Suppose $x\leqslant-1$ Then $x^3\leqslant-1^3=-1$ Thus $x^3-x\leqslant0$ Therefore $x^3-x\leqslant0$ #

Comment: No, you cannot subtract inequalities.

Comment: You have to be careful with your inequality because $x$ is negative so I would say you need to do a little more work to justify your "Then". "Thus" does not quite follow immediately from what came before either. You probably have in your head what you want to say, but you haven't quite got there on paper.

Comment: How do you get from $x^3\le -1$ to $x^3-x\le0$? Looks like a *non sequitur* to me.

Answer (score 4):

You see $y=x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ has roots $x=-1,0,1$. If $x<-1$ then $y$ will never touch zero again. Test by $x=-2$ and you have  $y=-6$ so all $y$ are negative for $x<-1$. In the same way, if $x>1$ then $y$ is positive since $y=6$ for $x=2$.

We can add that all polynomials are continuous so there are no discontinuous jumps over zero.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \leqslant -1$ then $x^{3}-x=(-x) \cdot (1-x^{2})$ which is the product if a positive number and a non-positive number. Hence $x^{3}-x\leqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$x\le -1\implies x^3\le -1\implies x^3-x=x^3+|x|\le -1+|x|=??$

There are many ways to do this correctly. Let $x=-r-1.$  Then $$x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x((-r-1)^2-1)=x(r^2+2r)=x\cdot (r)(r+2).$$ Now we have $$x\le -1\implies (x<0\, \land \, r\ge 0)\implies$$ $$ (x<0\,\land r\ge 0\,\land \, r+2 \ge 0+2>0)\implies$$ $$ (x<0\,\land (r)\,(r+2)\ge 0)\implies$$ $$ x\cdot (r)(r+2)\le 0.$$